# How can I scan a Kendo Grid and get each rows data?

Tags: kendo-grid

How can I scan a Kendo Grid and retrieve each row and its data.
I am trying the following but can't seem to see the data :

```
var grid = $("#mygrid");
var columns = $("#mygrid").data("kendoGrid").columns;
var rows = $("#mygrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length;
var noOfCols = columns.length;
var allrows = $("#mygrid").data("kendoGrid").items();                        
$("#mygrid").data("kendoGrid").items().each(function (a) {
    alert(a.text());
});
```

I need to check the value of a column in each row and if it is not a certain value the report tot the user. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Get Kendo Grid Selected Cell value:

```
var grid = $('#GridName').data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
var selectedValue = selectedItem.YourPropertyColumnName;
```

For selecting a row by index number use the following:

```
$('#GridMaster').data("kendoGrid").bind('dataBound', function (e) {
    this.element.find('tbody tr:eq(3)').addClass('k-state-selected')
    //or >>>
    var index = 3;
    this.element.find('tbody tr:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('k-state-selected')
});
```

Alternatively, in order to display the first row always "selected" in Kendo Grid:

```
$(function () {
    $('#GridMaster').data("kendoGrid").bind('dataBound', function (e) {
    this.element.find('tbody tr:first').addClass('k-state-selected')
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't actually select a row. unless Im missing something in the solution? Does the select , indirectly select each row ?

Comment: @Mel Just selects row by given index number. You may also have a look at my update.

Comment: @Mel Also don't forget to vote up and marked as answer if the given answer is helpful for you. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't see how this scans the rows and checks values in the cells ?

Comment: Did you try **this.element.find('tbody tr:eq(3)')**?